# Finding a more functional approach using Java Optional?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

I'm trying my hand at using Optional as much as I can over normal null checks; and I ran into a suggestion by my IDE (IntelliJ):

```
Can be replaced by a singular expression in functional style.
```

Here is the code in question, the line in question:

```
Entry entry = maybeBytes.isPresent() ? Entry.deserialize(maybeBytes.get()) : new Entry();
```

I've looked a bit [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html), but couldn't find a usage or at least see one that would fit my case here. I'm pretty new to the lambda features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
Entry entry = maybeBytes.map(Entry::deserialize).orElseGet(Entry::new);
```

If `maybeBytes` contains a value, it will be passed to the function you provide to `map()`, and you'll get an `Optional<Entry>` with the result (and if `maybeBytes` was empty, you'll get an empty `Optional<Entry>`). `orElseGet()` will give you the contents of the `Optional<Entry>` if it's nonempty, and otherwise, it will give you the result of evaluating the function you pass to it (in this case, the constructor of `Entry`).

Answer (score 3):

Pressing Alt+Enter when you see such suggestions will apply them, and you'll see the result yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was orElse() which fit to my needs. I do not needed to do extra deserialization.

instead of isPresent() combined with get() certainly does the trick…

```
return maybeBytes.isPresent() ? maybeBytes.get() : new Entry();
```

you can use

```
return maybeBytes.orElse(new Entry());
```